# rails database field security

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, field

enter code herein rails

```
@user = User.new(params[:id])
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
# params[:user] = {:admin => true, :name => "stackoverflow", ...}
```

in case
:admin is only permitted service administrator.

Developer didn't make  for admin(like  but some users insert  by force.

I want that some fields are only permitted by someone has permission(not normal user)

(in old times, i insert  by force.
public tumblr can not change to private tumblr but it is possible by inserting soem code lines)

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is attr_accessible.

from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  include ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :plan_id, :as => :admin

  def update
    ...
    @account.update_attributes(account_params)
    ...
  end

  protected

  def account_params
    role = admin ? :admin : :default
    sanitize_for_mass_assignment(params[:account], role)
  end

end
```

**note:**
This only works in rails > 3.0. If your version is smaller than 3, you can check out ryan bate's [dynamic attr accessible cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/237-dynamic-attr-accessible)